# Get Gerund of a verb

Tags: java, nlp, nlg

I'm new to Simple NLG, I want to get the gerund of the verb I enter.
here is a sample code, but i tried entering gerund for tense but it didn't work

```
XMLLexicon lexicon = new XMLLexicon("path\\to\\default-lexicon.xml");
WordElement word = lexicon.getWord("live", LexicalCategory.VERB);
InflectedWordElement infl = new InflectedWordElement(word);
infl.setFeature(Feature.TENSE, Tense.PAST); //I want the verb to be in gerund not past
Realiser realiser = new Realiser(lexicon);
String gerund = realiser.realise(infl).getRealisation();
System.out.println(gerund);
```

Comment: `but it didn't work` ... what didn't work, or what output are you getting?

Comment: the output is the verb in the past tense. because in line 4 u can see, Tense.PAST
I want to change the output to gerund except that there's no syntax Tense.GERUND so this is my problem. How to change this line or lines in my code so the output is gerund.

Comment: Can you check the documentation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the API, but from what I could piece together, it looks like an approach similar to

```
XMLLexicon lexicon = ...
NLGFactory phraseFactory = new NLGFactory(lexicon);
VPPhraseSpec live = phraseFactory.createVerbPhrase("live");
SPhraseSpec clause = phraseFactory.createClause();
clause.setVerbPhrase(live);
clause.setFeature(Feature.FORM, Form.GERUND);
Realizer realizer = new Realizer(lexicon);
String gerund = realizer.realize(clause).getRealisation();
```

Might be better for you.

Look at [the unit tests](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg/blob/master/src/test/java/simplenlg/syntax/english/ClauseTest.java) for hints on how to use an API if you cannot find a better resource.

Comment: Thank you ! That helped me reach the right code


        Lexicon lexicon = new NIHDBLexicon("C:\\Users\\BlackRain\\Desktop\\lexAccess2016 (1)\\lexAccess2016\\data\\HSqlDb\\lexAccess2016.data");
        NLGFactory phraseFactory = new NLGFactory(lexicon);
        VPPhraseSpec live = phraseFactory.createVerbPhrase("skim");
        SPhraseSpec clause = phraseFactory.createClause();
        clause.setVerbPhrase(live);
        clause.setFeature(Feature.FORM,Form.GERUND);
        Realiser realizer = new Realiser(lexicon);
        String gerund = realizer.realise(clause).getRealisation();

Comment: @JeremyHunts Glad you could piece together the last bits.  Happy to hear it worked.

Comment: @JeremyHunts Added the `Feature.FORM` parameter to the original question; because, it's pretty hard to read in the comment.